# Sorting after or while populating?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I  have an arbitrary number of files, where each file contains an arbitrary number of integers, with each line having one or more integers. The goal is to, as efficientrly as possible, be able to read each file, save each integer along with its line number in a dynamic data structure, sort the integers then print out the sorted sequence with the line number of each integer.

The number of integers in each file is arbitrary. It could be as small as 10 and as high as 200,000. That's why I'm thinking of implementing two different sort algorithms, one for small input and another for large input. This means I will have to first count the integers in a file while reading them, then sort them based on their size. Would it be *more efficient* to use one sorting algorithm and directly sort the integers while reading them from file?

If yes, which sorting algorithm would be best to handle the varying input size?

Comment: How do you plan to store the values and line numbers? When you sort are the line numbers involved in the sorting? As an example given number : line would 5 : 2 sort before 5 : 5?

Comment: Probably something you should just try both ways and benchmark. Depending on your data structures, one approach will probably be O(log n) insertion time for n insertions and the other will be O(1) time per insertion followed by a single O(n log n) sort. Which are both the same asymptotic complexity, so you'd really have to measure both approaches to see which is faster.

Comment: Although this analysis is assuming you can easily choose a data structure where insertion into the middle is O(1). If you have otherwise strong reasons to want to use a `std::vector` for your underlying container, for instance, then insertion into the middle is O(n) not O(1) and I would presumptively favor the "insert all, then sort" approach.

Comment: Could you just go with whatever you want to use for the large sample? I mean, if the sample is small anyway does it matter that the sort algorithm is not completely optimal?

Comment: 200 000 is still fairly small. I would go for convenience and stuff them into an `std::map<int(=integer),std::vector<int(=line number)>>` while reading; the standard map is a sorted structure (RB-tree) with O(log N) insertion. But if you want to be sure, implement both approaches (sort while reading vs. read first, sort later) and measure. Performance can often be counterintuitive.

Comment: @RetiredNinja No, line numbers are irrelevant in terms of sorting, and regarding the data structure to store the values, I'm thinking of a map but I'm still hesitant as to which data structure would be the most efficient in this case.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Efficiency is major factor here. Radix search, for example, is very quick in sorting large lists, but would perform completely the opposite way around if the list is small.